# DRF Serializer - Accept field but don't use it in `create` or `update`

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a model `Message` that has a `FileField`. My API accepts files in `Base64` encoding so they can be sent alongside other data.

To know a filename and an extension, there is one more field `attachment_filename` in the serializer that is not a model field. It is used inside `Base64Field`.

I want to be able to validate if there are both `attachment_filename` , `attachment`, or none of them.

The problem is that if the `attachment_filename` is read-only, it is not present in `validate` - `data` variable.

On the other hand, if it's `required=False`, `allow_null=True`, the serializer raises an error when creating a message:

```
TypeError: ChatMessage() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attachment_filename'
```

Code:

```
class Base64File(Base64FileField):  # todo make accept a list of extensions (finite eg. pdf, xlsx, csv, txt )
    ALLOWED_TYPES = ['pdf', 'xlsx', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'docx', 'doc', 'zip']

    def get_file_extension(self, filename, decoded_file):
        extension = self.get_full_name().split('.')[-1]
        return extension

    def get_file_name(self, decoded_file):
        attachment_filename = self.get_full_name()
        return '.'.join(attachment_filename.split('.')[:-1])

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.context['request'].data['attachment_filename']  # todo validate name

class ChatMessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attachment = Base64File(required=False)
    attachment_filename = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ChatMessage
        fields = '__all__'


    def validate(self, data):
        """
        Validation of start and end date.
        """
        attachment = data.get('attachment')
        attachment_filename = data.get('attachment_filename')
        if bool(attachment) ^ bool(attachment_filename):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Either none or both 'attachment' and 'attachment_filename' must be present")
        # del data['attachment_filename'] # works but dirty
        return data
```

How to make it work?

**EDIT**

I managed to make it work by adding

```
del data['attachment_filename']
```

before `validate` method return but that seems to be too "dirty".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle this behavior in `serializer.save` method, for example, you can pop it from `validated_data` like that:

```
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.validated_data.pop("attachment_filename")

        return super().save(**kwargs)
```